# frozen UI when working with core data .mainQueueConcurrencyType

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency

Problem: UI is frozen while working with core data with `.mainQueueConcurrencyType` thread

UI: Any `UI updates`, `UITable scrolling` etc, But in this question I use example of `SwiftSpinner` which is activity indicator,
https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner

setup :

iOS : 11.4 , device : iPhone 7 plus, Xcode: 9.4.1

my code looks like this

```
let bgContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)


func doCoreData(progress : @escaping (Double) -> ()) {
    bgContext.performAndWait {
        for i in 1...10{
            let cent : Double = Double(i)/Double(10)
            // do some coredata work adding and updating
            progress(cent)
            // hide SwiftSpinner at the end
            if i == 10 {
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
            }
        }
    }
}

func orgnizeThings (){
    doCoreData { (cent) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let perCent = cent * 100
            SwiftSpinner.show(progress: cent, title: "loading \(perCent)")
        }
    }
}
```

calling the `orgnizeThings()` function will get the **Core Data** work done but I would like to to show the user how far the function is done

in this setup the `SwiftSpinner` `UIView` is frozen

Comment: "some coredata work adding and updating" sounds non-trivial. You probably don't wanna do that on the main queue, because doing so will block your UI until it's done

Answer (score 4):

Core data is not thread safe. Changing the concurrency type from MainQueueConcurrencyType to PrivateQueueConcurrencyType can cause the app to crash if multiple threads are writing at the same time. Better approach would be to have multiple manage object contexts, with parent child relationship:

```
 let mainMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
 let childMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
 childMoc.parentContext = mainMoc

  childMOC.performBlock{
            for i in 1...10{
                let cent : Double = Double(i)/Double(10)
                // do some coredata work adding and updating
                progress(cent)

            }

            do {
                try childMoc.save()
                mainMOC.performBlockAndWait{
                    do {
                        try mainMoc.save()
                        SwiftSpinner.hide()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            } catch{
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }

  }
```

When the child context is saved, the changes go to the parent context. When the parent context is saved, changes go to the persistent store coordinator. The main thread won't be blocked, because all the heavy write operations will be done in the childMoc which is of PrivateConcurrencyType.

If the performance is still poor, it would be because writing from MainContext to disc is an expensive operation. Instead of parent context writing to the disc directly, you can create a master context which will write to the disc and Main context changes will go to Maser Context once the Main Context is saved.

[image]

For more details, read this medium post: https://medium.com/soundwave-stories/core-data-cffe22efe716

Comment: What do you think about not changing anything in mainContext at all?

Comment: If MainContext is writing to the persistent store, and at the same time let's assume a user is trying to scroll, there would be performance issues. I think it makes lot of sense to use Worker Context and Master Context for having a smooth user experience, and hence changing anything on the main context should be avoided.

Comment: Wouldn't main context be a bottleneck here? I know saving to a parent context is probably not as expensive as saving to disk, but you could still block the UI when trying to read from the main context while at the same time saving to the master context. Wouldn't it be better to have main and worker contexts both be children of master? Main context can then strictly be read only. You'd have to subscribe to save notifications, and manage merging, but you'd avoid UI performance issues.